# How to load a custom class inherited from existing one?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an object of a class, using just a name of this class:

```
public interface Foo {
}
public class Bar implements Foo {
}
[...]
Class<Foo> c = Class.forName("com.XXX.Bar").asSubclass(Foo.class);
Foo foo = c.newInstance();
```

Compiler says:

```
incompatible types found : 
java.lang.Class<capture#47 of ? extends com.XXX.Foo>
required: java.lang.Class<com.XXX.Foo>
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `c` is a *some class which extends `Foo`*, you should express it in the code using `<? extends ...>` syntax:

```
Class<? extends Foo> c = Class.forName("com.XXX.Bar").asSubclass(Foo.class);
```